# Magnetic forces in physics

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, quantum-electrodynamics

Could an accelerator be built in which all forces on the particles, for steering and for increasing speed, are magnetic forces? Why or Why not?

Comment: By "stirring" do you mean "steering"?

Comment: are you familiar with the Lorentz force and how it affects speed as it is always perpendicular to the charge's velocity vector?

Comment: @hyportnex Regardless, the Lorentz force is not necessarily the only thing that needs to be considered. A very impractical accelerator could be built that uses magnetic field gradients to do work on the intrinsic magnetic dipole moment of fermions.

Comment: @probably_someone yes, you are right, but somebody who is asking this question will have difficulty understanding that argument and Lorentz force is or should be part of basic EM courses...

Comment: @probably_someone The Lorentz force is all there is. If it isn't a Lorentz force, it isn't electromagnetic. In classical electrodynamics, which is the topic here.

Comment: @my2cts "If it isn't a Lorentz force, it isn't electromagnetic." Counterexample: ultracold neutrons which are levitated in a magnetic bowl in experiments like UCN$\tau$. What would you call the interaction between the neutron intrinsic magnetic dipole moment and the magnetic field of a permanent magnet except "electromagnetic"? For that matter, why are we assuming that the question is restricted to classical electrodynamics? The OP asked about particle accelerators, which can utilize the force on particles' intrinsic magnetic dipole moments to create polarized beams (see e.g. CEBAF).

Comment: You still have to prove that this is not covered by the Lorentz force formula. I assume that a neutron does not behave differently than a dipole formed by a current loop, which _is_ described by the Lorentz force. Yes the discussion is about particle physics, as you say.

Answer (score -1):

No. 
Because **Magnetic Forces Do No Work**.

Magnetic forces on charged particles are given by:
$$ \vec F = q \vec v \times \vec B $$

The cross product guarantees $\vec F$ is always perpendicular to the velocity $\vec v$. Therefore the magnetic force cannot increase the magnitude of the velocity, only the direction.  That means you cannot increase the kinetic energy of the particle either, which is usually the point of an accelerator.

Comment: Magnetic forces do no work **on point-like electric charges with no magnetic multipole moments**. Fermions have a magnetic dipole moment, and magnetic field gradients _can_ do work on those.

Comment: Can they increase kinetic energy though ??????

Comment: @AdityaGarg If the objects whose kinetic energy you're trying to increase have no magnetic dipole moment, then no, because magnetic fields can do no work on such objects, hence no energy can be transferred.

Comment: Steering rather